# What is the ratio of areas of quadrilaterals ABFE and EFCD??

Tags: geometry, area

$ABCD$ is a trapezium with parallel sides $AB = a$ and $DC = b$. If E and F are mid-points of nonparallel sides AD and BC respectively, then what is the ratio of areas of quadrilaterals $ABFE$ and $EFCD$ in terms of $a$ and $b$??

Is there any relation between the length of parallel sides and the length of line joining the midpoint of non parallel sides of a trapezium?If yes, please also tell me the derivation.

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked 5 questions during last few hours. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean a quadrilateral with a pair of parallel opposite sides (as the word trapezium has different definitions around the world).

As the sides $AD$ and $BC$ are linear and $E$ and $F$ are their midpoints, then $|EF| = \frac{1}{2} (|AB| + |CD|) = (a + b)/2$ as the points are in the middle. (Think about this statement a little, I don't want to give it all away).

Then let the height of the original trapezium $ABCD$ be $h$. So the areas of the different shapes are as follows by the standard rules for area of a trapezoid:

$[ABCD] = h(a + b)/2$

$[ABFE] = h(a + (a+b)/2)/4 = h(3a/2 + b/2)/4 = h(3a + b)/8$

$[EFCD] = h(b + (a+b)/2)/4 = h(3b/2 + a/2)/4 = h(3b + a)/8$

Its easy to see then that $[ABFE]/[EFCD] = (3a + b)/(3b + a)$ and that $[ABFE]/[ABCD] = (3a + b)/(4a + 4b)$ and $[EFCD]/[EFCD] = (3b + a)/(4a + 4b)$.

Comment: I got the result that $|EF| = \frac{1}{2} (|AB| + |CD|) = (a + b)/2.$It is obtained by using the mid-point theorem in $\triangle s ADC$ and $ACB$ isn't it?

Comment: @ Chinmay Nirkhe How did you get the result [ABFE] = h(a + (a+b)/2)/2 and [EFCD] = h(b + (a+b)/2)/2 ??

Comment: @Chinmay There might be some typos in the first and second statement of your last sentence.

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA. My original result of $[ABFE] = h(a + (a+b)/2)/2$ was off by a factor of 2. The correct result is $[ABFE] = h(a + (a+b)/2)/4$ as it as a trapezium of height $h/2$, base $(a+b)/2)$ and top $a$.

Comment: @ChinmayNirkhe An obvious error still exists even after fixing.